# How to disable authorization for /restart endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, application-restart

I try to implement restart feature in my web application.

I've added following dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:1.2.4.RELEASE")
```

In start logs I found that post /restart was registered.

I decided to request this url:

[image]

But result is fail. I understand that this url should be protected but I have custom authorization/authentication mechanism and I don't have rights to change it.

Is there way to disable protection for this url? A better way - to have service which I can inject inside my controller and invoke. Is there something inside the spring to solve my problem?

Comment: Just disable it in you WebConfig...
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-httpsecurity

Comment: @Herr Derb, actualyy I don't have spring security in classpath

Comment: So where does the security come from then???

Comment: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MvcEndpointSecurityInterceptor#isUserAllowedAccess

Comment: @Herr Derb, I use cuetom security mechanism. This mechanism is not related with spring

Comment: Did you inject `@Autowired private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;`?

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Munna - no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
endpoints.restart.enabled = true
management.security.enabled=false
```

Comment: maybe you know how to remap urls? I just need to do some additional checks related with my custom authentification in controller

Comment: Update your answer with the correct one `endpoints.restart.enabled = true` @AndriyBr.

Answer (score 2):

Reason is that spring cloud enabled the security for endpoints by default.You need disable security for management (because /restart endpoint is an additional endpoint for management), in properties:

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

to remap endpoints from ../restart to /foo/restart, you need to add additional property:

```
management.context-path=/foo
```

To implement your custom end point, you just have to implement interface Endpoint and override its methods.

to disable default restart endpoint:

```
endpoints.restart.enabled=false
```

Comment: I want register my own controller for this url. Is it possible?

Comment: At this case I see that spring url has more priority

Comment: first of all you need to disable default /restart endpoint endpoints.restart.enabled=false, and then make your own implementation of this /restart endpoint. Or you can add custom endpoint, to do this, you just have to implement interface Endpoint and override its methods.

Comment: in case if I use **endpoints.restart.enabled=false** and then in controller I do  **restartMvcEndpoint.invoke** - it responds that "This endpoint is disabled"

Comment: I tried to autowire **import org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartEndpoint** but at this case I see that application inly shutdowns and not up

Comment: of course if you disable this endpoint it can not be autowired.